# Retrieve iterator position from mpl fold expression

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates, boost-mpl

How can I obtain the index of the following folded type with `boost::mpl` (which is some kind of mpl::set but not quite). The `value iter::pos::value` is somehow not defined??

```
using unique_types =
            typename mpl::fold<
            mpl::vector<int,double,float,float,float>
            , mpl::set0<>
            , mpl::insert<mpl::placeholders::_1, mpl::placeholders::_2> /** _1 = State = set<...>, _2 element of NodeTypes*/
            >::type;

        using iter =  typename boost::mpl::find< unique_types , int>::type;

std::cout << iter::pos::value << std::endl;  // <<<< Not defined!
```

Compile online : [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ab67af9e3b8cf0d1)

Answer (score 0):

```
using types = mpl::vector<int, double, float, float, float>
using unique_types<types, mpl::set0<>, mpl::insert<_1, _2>>::type;
using iter = mpl::find<unique_edge_types, int>::type;
// std::cout << iter::pos::value << std::endl;
// error: 'boost::mpl::iter<boost::mpl::s_item<...a lot of text... > >::pos'
//        has not been declared (mpl::s_item is a piece of mpl::set implementation)
```

While **edge_types** is an *mpl::vector*, **unique_edge_types** is (up to implementation details) an *mpl::set*, and *mpl::find* does not work with *mpl::set*. A similar error occurs for

```
using unique_types = mpl::set<int, double, float>;
using iter = mpl::find<unique_types, int>::type;
// std::cout << iter::pos::value << std::endl;
// error: 'boost::mpl::iter<boost::mpl::set<...a lot of text... > >::pos'
//        has not been declared
```

You can use the standard function *mpl::unique* returning an *mpl::vector*:

```
#include <boost/mpl/unique.hpp>
#include <boost/type_traits/is_same.hpp>

using unique_types = mpl::unique<types, boost::is_same<_1,_2>>::type;
```